# How can I use Typescript generics to properly relate the arguments to my function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, formik

I want to replace `sadValidate` with `happyValidate` but I can't get my generic typings to work out on `makeValidate`.

```
type ValidationFn = (s: string) => boolean;

interface Validation {
  check: ValidationFn;
  message: string;
}

const validIdentityNameCharacters = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-\s]*$/;
const hasSpecialCharacters: Validation = {
  check: s => !validIdentityNameCharacters.test(s),
  message: 'Must only include letters, numbers and the following special characters: (_ -.)',
};

const LIMIT = 255;
const isLengthTooLong: Validation = {
  check: s => s.length >= LIMIT,
  message: `Must be less than ${LIMIT} characters`,
};

const isBlank: Validation = { check: s => s === '', message: 'Must not be blank' };

interface Values {
  name: string;
  tags: string;
}

const sadValidate = (values: Values): Partial<Values> => {
  const errors: Partial<Values> = {};
  const { name, tags } = values;

  if (hasSpecialCharacters.check(name)) {
    errors.name = hasSpecialCharacters.message;
  } else if (isLengthTooLong.check(name)) {
    errors.name = isLengthTooLong.message;
  } else if (isBlank.check(name)) {
    errors.name = isBlank.message;
  }

  if (isLengthTooLong.check(tags)) {
    errors.tags = isLengthTooLong.message;
  }

  return errors;
};

const makeValidate = config => values =>
  Object.keys(config).reduce((acc, fieldName) => {
    const validators = config[fieldName];
    const problem = validators.find(({ check }) => check(values[fieldName]));
    if (problem) {
      acc[fieldName] = problem.message;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});

const happyValidate = makeValidate({
  name: [hasSpecialCharacters, isLengthTooLong, isBlank],
  tags: [isLengthTooLong],
});

test('works', () => {
  expect(happyValidate({ name: '', tags: new Array(260).fill('a').join('') })).toEqual({
    name: isBlank.message,
    tags: isLengthTooLong.message,
  });
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-agnesi-t71jiq?file=/src/index.spec.ts

this works but it's a lot of `as`...

```
export const makeValidate =
  <V>(config: Record<keyof V, Validation[]>) =>
  (values: V): Record<keyof V, string> =>
    Object.keys(config).reduce<Record<keyof V, string>>((acc, fieldName) => {
      const validators = config[fieldName as keyof V];
      const problem = validators.find(({ check }) => check(values[fieldName as keyof V] as string));
      if (problem) {
        acc[fieldName as keyof V] = problem.message;
      }
      return acc;
    }, {} as Record<keyof V, string>);
```

Comment: so what is the problem? can you produce minimal example?

Comment: @AcidCoder, the issue is that `makeValidate` doesn't have typings. If you click the codesandbox link, you'll see the compile errors

Answer (score 1):

You can apply generics to your entire validation system, as demonstrated in this [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=46&ssc=83&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBM7CQewHYDFsA8AKgHxQC8UAFMAFxRECUFZARppghHNgNwBQ-UJFiJU6LISIUoAZ2AAnJNgDmZSgG9+UHQGMAFhF0BrevGRoMOfMRIAabToC2EWbLgqI9eUtX8AvoLC0OYArq4yAEpGmAooBD7KKnZQodjG2JgA7tgkAsFQAKIKCrGyBDBQEAAewBDYKLKiCOGy6lAaUADaANJQylDGECCYAGawALoA-N6KSVD++eDQAMI4o0gqFVW19Y3Nre2dvf3Yg8Njk2ZilpIVvRMkXRMLAvy6OPJQAG43AJIoeoYUAAOTgLhW+jgCjgujqCialAA9AA9LpwAC0AC8AIIYgBaAAYMQBOAD6ADoMQAdWQTABUABIkQIPtgvlDZABlSC6JCISHQ2Hw2TXCwSHAyLR6QwmbwsKAAQl+FgBQKQoPBEEFMLhEARFLq8ioskYDmcrncnnoAHIALKhL44BAgU66FqAqBcYAilLYUJOVj6po8FBQYCGKCjTgIbLzWS8-kIKAGIV6hH0KhkqAYimMG0ORaCNlfAAyfztf2klAATABWOusz7AfqyUv1FQRogcUs4FRi8RWM6aRwGIymOQK2QUriqCNQEiUcuVojmqAuNweLxQAAGDq+Qa9lvDULOjI0y6r-hTUN1Ip3hbeJZbSFkACEEDwJ+ZB5IpTfx3lcgyERchKBtAt10tLdbX3FtMhbQ9WE-dIbVeYtm3XOAhh-SxoEobYajqBomjCVwSCoNkNn7KA1mwaiKhIZhgOoFVWjMRh6GKUoEUYhVpT0TD9R40UihKMo+M0QJHCjWJqG9c5XQGNjXGYASdB0aMFHkiAWxVX9JUuKjNi6IYQAmNSZI0jSkHGKh9NuHAKTHEx7MQVpTOGCzLOs3yNOEspPPMmQHIlbAKQ3K0IAEPy-NYBRuGMGLYoWKydECDTpI0hLgFCBQzgChEBCLd5MKhMAwBAXD0HwrCcJuGqqAE7AtXoLpOR5Iwkx1YVgxSV92znfRu0wXtVH698UOMCY12ADxRK6AaOy7Hs+xmgJGCfT5OAgGdMBUKhysq6q6iaqAWpcW1ILmlRROwCAsigHESjgEAqBrAA2QlGApDYEAQKgbTgG0foAK0wZRAZBhZGE2oA). This will provide your with type safety throughout, without any need for casts or compiler assertions.

To break it down, first off, apply generics to your `ValidationFn` and `Validation` types so that they accept any type of value (yet default to string):

```
type ValidationFn<T> = (t: T) => boolean;

type Validation<T = string> = {
   check: ValidationFn<T>,
   message: string
}
```

Then define a base `Values` type:

```
type Values = Record<string, unknown>;
```

Use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to derive your `Errors` and `Config` types from the `Values` type:

```
type Errors<V extends Values> = { [K in keyof V]?: string };

type Config<V extends Values> = { [K in keyof V]: Validation<V[K]>[] };
```

Reuse your existing validation methods as-is:

```
const validIdentityNameCharacters = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-\s]*$/;
const hasSpecialCharacters: Validation = {
  check: s => !validIdentityNameCharacters.test(s),
  message: 'Must only include letters, numbers and the following special characters: (_ -.)',
};

const LIMIT = 255;
const isLengthTooLong: Validation = {
  check: s => s.length >= LIMIT,
  message: `Must be less than ${LIMIT} characters`,
};

const isBlank: Validation = { check: s => s === '', message: 'Must not be blank' };
```

Use a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) for the new `makeValidate()` function:

```
const makeValidate = <V extends Values>(config: Config<V>) => (values: V): Errors<V> => {
   const errors: Errors<V> = {}

   for (let key in values) {
      for (let validation of config[key]) {
         if (validation.check(values[key])) {
            errors[key] = validation.message;
            break;
         }
      }
   }

   return errors;
};
```

Reuse your existing pattern for the `happyValidate()` function:

```
const happyValidate = makeValidate({
  name: [hasSpecialCharacters, isLengthTooLong, isBlank],
  tags: [isLengthTooLong],
});
```

And test to see that it all works:

```
console.log(happyValidate({ name: '', tags: new Array(260).fill('a').join('') }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generically type it like this:

```
type ValidationConfig<K extends string> = Record<K, Array<Validation>>
type ValidationValues<K extends string> = Record<K, string>
type ValidationResult<K extends string> = Record<K, string>

const makeValidate = 
    <K extends string>(config: ValidationConfig<K>) => 
    (values: ValidationValues<K>) => {
        const keys = Object.keys(config) as Array<K> // required because Object.keys returns string[]
        return keys.reduce((acc, fieldName) => {
            const validators = config[fieldName];
            const problem = validators.find(({ check }) => check(values[fieldName]));
            if (problem) {
                acc[fieldName] = problem.message;
            }
            return acc;
        }, {} as ValidationResult<K>); // required because we can't add fields to an empty object {}
    }
```

Note that you have to use some casts to work around the way that Object.keys is not typed very specifically.